# Setting the Wallpaper from an Image on the SDCard

Tags: android, sd-card

How would one go about setting the homescreen wallpaper from an image on the SDcard?

i.e.:

```
try {
    wallpaperManager.setResource("/sdcard/wallpaper/olive.jpg");
    finish();
} catch(IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

hasn't worked, returned an error: 'The method setResource(int) in the type WallpaperManager is not applicable for the arguments (String)'

Answer (score 3):

```
Bitmap o = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/sdcard/wallpapers/olive.jpg");

try {
  wallpaperManager.setBitmap(o);
  finish();
} 
catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```