# Need to set background of live wallpaper using images from sd card

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Setting the Wallpaper from an Image on the SDCard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3208708/setting-the-wallpaper-from-an-image-on-the-sdcard)

i am working on live wallpapers .i need to display images from sd card as live wallpaper background . image must be displayed as grid view on only first and third home screens. can anybody help me

i have checked the question Choosing background for live wallpaper but i am missing some code

so i have requested Dean to post his whole code 
please anybody help .Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You better try with below code for setting the image as a wallpaper from SDCard. But, you have to populate the images from sdcard to GridView. Probably you can use these blogs [displaying-images-from-sd-card](http://mihaifonoage.blogspot.in/2009/09/displaying-images-from-sd-card-in.html) and [Images from sdcard to Gridview](http://mihaifonoage.blogspot.in/2009/11/displaying-images-from-sd-card-in.html)  of listing the images from sdcard to gridview.

```
Bitmap o = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/Auntumn.jpg");

try {
  wallpaperManager.setBitmap(o);
  finish();
} 
catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```